# Remove jquery datepicker from a html control

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, readonly

I have a datepicker on a textbox `txtDate`. I need to remove the datepicker, if a particular checkbox `chkBox` is checked. And to reapply the datepicker if the checkbox is not checked.

I tried making the textbox readonly, but datepicker is still working. How to do this.

EDIT: On the same checkbox event, I also want to make a select (dropdown) control as non selectable. No one should be able to change what in the select control.

Answer (score 5):

In your `change` handler for the checkbox you can call `enable` or `disable` on the datepicker, for example:

```
$("#chkBox").change(function() {
  $("#txtDate").attr("readonly", this.checked)
               .datepicker(this.checked ? "disable" : "enable");
  //for your edit:
  $("#someSelect").attr("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

[You can try it out in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/CDJFG/1/).